# how to get glLookAt's values once rotated

Tags: c++, opengl

so if I were to have this code

```
gluLookAt(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 
          0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
          0.0, 1.0, 0.0); //Set the point looking at

glRotatef(-90, 0.0,1.0,0.0);
```

how can i then get each value of the new glLookAt

Comment: you can stop using the old pipeline and manage your own matrices, then you don't have to calculate back and forth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to go the route of using `glGetDoublev` to get the GL_MODELVIEW and GL_PROJECTION matrixes.